# How do I remove unnecessary console message pop up PhantomJS Selenium with python 3?

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

Every time When i run my Selenium script with phantomjs driver a massage pop up in the console automatically,

[image: The pop up message]

I can remove it ?

this my code

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('https:/example.com')
```

Comment: it is only warning - don't bother this. But you should rather bother  what is in this warning. `PhantomJS` is abandome project and one day it may not work.

Comment: always put code, data and error message as text, not image

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard module [warnings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) to configure what warning to display.

For example you can ignore all warnings

```
import warnings

warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
```

but it may ignore other useful warnings

---

```
import warnings
from selenium import webdriver

warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('https:/example.com')
```